# mmap: No such device

Tags: python, mmap, glusterfs

I'm trying to follow a bug through python, now bringing me to ansi-c's mmap.

```
import os, mmap
filename = <name to ntfs file>
os.path.exists(filename) # is true
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    # f.fileno() is 3 or 19 (not -1)
    mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 1, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ, offset=0)
    # OSError [19]: No such device
    # this is thrown by:
    #    cpython/Modules/mmapmodule.c:1188
    # apparently b/c systems `mmap` (line 1177) can't
    # find the memory.
```

Here's the mount info of the ntfs directory

```
jtschw2@compi:~/Code/cpython$ mount | grep labs
bmidata2:cliff.tcp on /labs/cliff type fuse.glusterfs (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,max_read=131072)
```

Now this is all on CentOS7.  Where do you think I should go from here?  Is this unmappable memory, or is it something we can fix?

Related is possibly [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/d15TSWcscU4).  The problem occured when using `numpy.memmap`.

> Why does it say paper jam when there is no paper jam!

Comment: Are you using the built-in python mmap, or numpy.memmap? Your question is contradictory.

Comment: `numpy.memmap.__init__` uses `mmap.mmap` in numpy/core/memmap.py:264, my friend.

Comment: So you aren't showing us the actual code you are using? Please edit that into your question or nobody will be able to help you. (See stack overflow guidelines about MCVE)

Comment: @mbrig, I provide a concise minimal example that reproduces the error on my machine, and I just found out why the error is generated, which I will share shortly.  I have a question too:  Why did you downvote my post?

Comment: You are either mentioning numpy and memmap pointlessly, making your question harder to understand, or your actual code is different that what you have posted (ansi-c is a similarly irrelevant tag, as far as I can tell). The code in your question runs without issue on my system (from linux, looking at a file on ntfs),

Comment: @mbrig, i understand your confusion. However, given the problem's solution, numpy.memmap doesn't set the right flags numpy/core/memmap.py:264 (see this pull). Because numpy.memmap doesn't catch that error it's a likely point of encounter, and relevant to numpy users specifically. Can you agree with that? Now I didn't know where the bug was at first. That's why I put all these tags on it. You're downvote is a bit harsh I think.  Can you remove your vote now?

Answer (score 4):

Indeed it's a problem with fuse.  [Apparently](http://community.mrtrix.org/t/mrtrix-mmap-gpfs-issue/710), my version of glusterfs still has problems with mmap in the shared mode, e.g. `mmap(.., flags=mmap.MAP_SHARED, ..)`.  This is resolved by replacing `MAP_SHARED` by `MAP_PRIVATE`:

```
import os, mmap
filename = <name to ntfs file>
os.path.exists(filename) # is true
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    mmap.mmap(
        f.fileno(), 1, prot=mmap.PROT_READ,
        flags=mmap.MAP_PRIVATE, offset=0)
```

Then everything is peachy again :)